# Adding particles from particles.js in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, particles.js

I am facing some trouble including `particles.js` output (API provided by `shinyparticles` in `shinydashboard`. I am working with `R`.

Following is an example that works for `shiny`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyparticles)
    ui <- fluidPage(
           particles(),
           headerPanel("This is a sample app")
          )
    server <- function(input, output, session){}

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And here is one for `shinydashboard` that does not seem to work

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyparticles)
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(tags$body(div(particles()))),
    title = "Dashboard example",
    skin = "black"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

The resulting HTMLs seem identical when I view the page source, but the viz for particles does not appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particles don't appear because they are below the `dashboardBody` (by default: `z-index: -10`).

If you set the `z-index` of the particles to `1` they will be visible, **however any element you add to the body will be under the particles**.

[image: Particles above elements]

So set elements `z-index` to a higher number. (in this example I only use boxes)

**Code**:

```
dashboardBody(
  tags$head(tags$style("
    .particles-full {
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .box {
      z-index: 2;
    }
  ")),
  particles(),
  box(
    h2("Header"),
    p("Paragraph")
  ),
  box(
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)
```

**Output**: 
[image: Element above particles]